# SQL Server : Why select and then insert, in this query?

Tags: sql-server

this is a snippet from a stored procedure. Here t16M is a Tally table with 16 million rows.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable WITH(TABLOCKX) (Col1, Col2)
SELECT REPLICATE(N'X', 4000), REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS nvarchar(MAX)), 10000)
FROM t16M
WHERE num <= 100000;
```

I understand that it inserts values 'X....' into the two columns in TestTable for 100000 rows. What I don't understand is why cannot it be just:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable WITH(TABLOCKX) (Col1, Col2) FROM t16M WHERE num <= 100000;
```

? because the Tally table contains only one column?

Comment: Are you wanting a special case for when you're running a select purely for the side effect of generating a set number of rows, where the data in the select doesn't depend on the actual data in the tables involved in the select? Do you not think that such a special case would be rather contrived, for a general database system?

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable WITH(TABLOCKX) (Col1, Col2) FROM t16M WHERE num <= 100000;`

The above `INSERT` which you consider should be correct will insert in `Col1` and `Col2` columns of dbo.TestTable.

But what columns or values **FROM** t16M do you want to copy into `Col1` and `Col2`?

Your version of the query does not specify any values (either hardcoded - REPLICATE) or selected (columns) from another table to be put into `Col1` and `Col2`.

If your `TestTable` is not created yet, then you might want to take a look at `SELECT INTO`.

```
SELECT REPLICATE(N'X', 4000) AS Col1
    ,REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 10000) AS Col2
INTO dbo.TestTable
WITH (TABLOCKX)
FROM t16M
WHERE num <= 100000
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "select and then insert" in your query. The query inserts the results of a select, plain and simple. There is no `insert from` syntax in MS SQL - your "alternate" query doesn't compile :)

The `select` part of the original query projects the values to be passed into `Col1` and `Col2` of `dbo.TestTable`. So the query isn't actually saying anything more complicated than

> Insert 100000 rows of (ALotOfXXX, EvenMoreXXX) into dbo.TestTable

There isn't really a shorter way to say that.